# Mach-O Could Not Be Built

Tags: swift, build, fatal-error, mach-o

Everytime i try to code something this happens
Proof:[Mach-O file couldn’t be generated.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eTAc.jpg)

I tried to make the best car hud but that happened.
My expectations:I expected it to start.
I really don’t like that
Especially when my code fails.i’m so disappointed.
So yeah if i resolved it i will say.
[Steps To Reproduce]
1.Remove All Code From ContentView
2.Type your code (all of this on ipados 16.0 and above)
3.Run
4.It doesn’t work T_T

Comment: Can anyone give me a clue as to why is this happening?